# keep getting action creator is not a function when setting up incrementing button

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm somewhat new to React and Redux so I could be missing something obvious. But I'm stuck and google has left me with more confusion than help.

I'm making a simple app that has dogs, each dog has a sort of "like" or "incrementing" button that gives a + 1 every time it's clicked.

Well every time I try clicking it I get "this.addLikes is not a function".

Component
DogList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { dogs } from "../public/data.js";
import { addLikes } from "./actions/addLikes";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class DogList extends Component {
  handleClick = (dog) => {
    console.log("was clicked!");
    this.addLikes(dog.id);
  };

  render() {
    console.log(dogs);

    return (
      <div>
        {dogs.map((dog) => (
          <div key={dog.id} className="dog-card">
            <p> Name: {dog.name}</p>
            <p> Breed: {dog.breed}</p>
            <p> Known For: {dog.knownFor}</p>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, dog.id)}>0</button>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addLikes })(DogList);
```

Action
addLikes.js

```
export function addLikes(state) {
  return {
    type: "LIKED",
    payload: state
  };
}
```

Reducer
likesReducer.js

```
export default function likesReducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LIKED":
      return { ...(state.likes + 1) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: read react-redux documents about how to use connect api : https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `this.props.addLikes`.

But be warned: this is an **incredibly** outdated way of doing things and if you are just learning this, you should stay away from the tutorial you are following!

You should **not** be using class components in 2023. The React ecosystem has moved on to function components with hooks. Also, you should not use `connect/mapStateToProps`, as those are a legacy API that is only required for compatibility with class components.
Going forward, you should be using `useSelector/useDispatch`. Also, your Redux style here is very outdated. Modern Redux (since 2019) does not use switch..case reducers, ACTON_TYPES or immutable reducer logic.
You can read up on modern Redux [here](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and also take the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Comment: Thanks, I learned this from a coding school 3 months ago. I'm honestly not surprised that their curriculum is outdated. I'll be checking out that official tutorial for sure!

Comment: All of that is pre-2019 - including React class components. Unfortunately, many trainers never recheck their sources and just keep teaching the same stuff over and over. I would be very grateful if you could tell them (also about the [new React documentation](https://react.dev/), by now it's very explicit about not recommending class components).